# Play stream audio in background with notification control using exoplayer

Tags: notifications, media-player, exoplayer, background-service, foreground-service

iam learning app development so it is very important for me if you people guide me. I have main activity and and two fragments, 1 for listitem and another for now playing. When clicked list item it pass the url to 2nd(now playing) fragment and start playing the music, everything going normal but i want to do this in background/foreground service with notifications control and i want to use exoPlayer or which one is better to stream deferent types of audio. Please guys i need to achieve this in any how help me. Waiting for yours answer. Thank you